# JQuery Appending to End of Table Row Instead of Tbody?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, html-table, append

I am trying to loop through objects, and when certain strings that match an array are hit, a table row should be appended to the table with that string in a cell.

The output is working successfully, however, instead of appending the new rows below the prior ones, they are being added onto the current row, so I have one super long row instead of five shorter width ones. I found out that if I did the same thing outside the loop, it worked, as desired, but inside the loop, it doesn't. Perhaps the loop is causing problems because I'm appending to the same tr?

HTML:

```
<table id="tableMemberResults">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Member</th>
            <th>Bill To</th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Hours</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var tbody = $("#tableMemberResults tbody");
var userTr = $('<tr>');
```

...

```
for (i in users) {
            if (typeof users[i] == "object") {
                if (userArray.indexOf(i) >= 0) {
                    $('<td>').html(i).appendTo(userTr).css("background-color", "#ffba59");
                    $('<td colspan = "3">').html("").appendTo(userTr).css("background-color", "#ffba59");
                    tbody.append(userTr);
                }
                recursiveIter(users[i]);
            }

    $('<td>').html(i).appendTo(userTr).css("background-color", "#ffba59");
    $('<td colspan = "3">').html("").appendTo(userTr).css("background-color", "#ffba59");
    tbody.append(userTr);
}
```

As mentioned above, I copied the code I had and used a new tr variable outside of the loop and it worked. Below are my changes.

HTML:

```
var trTest = $('<tr>');
```

JS:

```
$('<td>').html("this is a test").appendTo(trTest).css("background-color", "#ffba59");
$('<td colspan = "3">').html("").appendTo(trTest).css("background-color", "#ffba59");
tbody.append(trTest);
```

This works perfectly. I still have my massive long row of code, but the new trTest row was appended correctly as a separate row. The only difference is that I'm outside of my for loop.

What do I need to change in my loop for it to work properly?

Edit: Here is the new block of code based on Dan's suggestion

```
$('<td>').html(i).appendTo($('<tr>')).css("background-color", "#ffba59");
$('<td colspan = "3">').html("").appendTo($('<tr>')).css("background-color", "#ffba59");
tbody.append($('<tr>'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you create one `userTr` and then append to it over and over.  Drop the variable and replace with `$('<tr>')` and you'll get a new tr every time.

You'll also want to append to the tbody (or the table itself) the new tr.

Comment: Dan,

I tried the new code for that section based on your suggestion. However, I now get no rows at all. I must be doing something wrong.

I am quite a novice to JS/JQuery, so please forgive my ignorance. I have posted the new code as an edit in my post.

Comment: Thank you Dan! I figured it out. It actually did work with a variable, but the issue was that I was declaring the variable outside of the loop, so it was only created once instead of a new tr being created every time it looped.

Comment: Yes indeed.  The variable will work as long as its within the loop.